# i have a issue with a multiple calls to web api service

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

i have a issue with a multiple calls to web api service,
i try to explain how its working:
- I have a instance of proxy that makes the calls to web api
- Many thread access the same instance of TProxy and call his method execute with differents input parameters.

The problem is that sometimes differents caller receive the answer belonging to other threads.

I wrote a very simplified code, 
any suggestions to deepen the subject

```
public class Tproxy
{
private object _lock=new object()


public string execute(string input_parameter)
{
    lock(_lock)
    {
        return StaticMethod(input_parameter)
    }
}


public static  string StaticMethod(string input_parameter)
{
    string res="";
    string url="some address.....";

                try
                {
                    using (var wb = new System.Net.WebClient())
                    {
                        var response = wb.UploadValues(url, "POST", data);
                        res=Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);

                        response=null;
                        ris=true;
                    }
                }
                catch ( System.Exception ee )  { ....... }

    return res;
}
}
```

The problem was much more evident without the " lock() statement", but also with it sometime it appens.

I solved the issue with some checks,  but i want to unsderstant what's real problem.

Each call invokes the method and should be kept waiting until the answer, eventually synchronization problems should occur later but I do not understand why they "mix" each other their result

The lock statemente in this context is real necessary? (any thread will create however the own System.Net.WebClient call)

Comment: I can't see any reason why the lock would be required in that example.  Static methods cannot 'see' non-static data.

Comment: Why would you need synchronization at all? Can your `TProxy` just handle simultaneous calls?

Comment: the lock statement is used in the instance method not in the static, and also I think the It wouldn't be necessary, but it works, without it the problem is much more evident.  Why they receive the answer belonging other thread? this is the real question